# SearchControls in java naming - anyone have any experience with this query optimizer?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ldap

I'm curious as to what benefits `SearchControls` (in `javax.naming.directory`) gives me to my LDAP query.

As I understand `Scope = ONELEVEL_SCOPE` will give me performance improvements if i know my elements are all on one level. `SUBTREE_SCOPE` will iterate through all branches.

Are there any other things i can tweak on this object that might give me performance improvements? What are peoples experience with this object?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a 'query optimizer'. It just provides information to the server that bounds the search.

Make sure all the attributes you're searching in have appropriate indexes. Some LDAP servers will refuse to perform the search if you don't.